# What is the best standing wave ratio one can get for a transmission line?

Tags: transmission-line

This is a bit newbie question but as far as I know the SWR is given as:

> SWR = (1+|\$\Gamma\$|) / (1-|\$\Gamma\$|)

where \$\Gamma\$ is the reflection coefficient.

But what is the best standing wave ratio one can obtain in theory and in practice? And what does it tell us about the received signal.

Comment: What do you get when Γ = 0?

Comment: I dont know how to interpret "best SWR" here. If SWR bigger signal reception/radiation is better or the other way around?

Comment: Well, you're the one who used the word "best" -- so what did you mean by it? Most people would consider a reflection coefficient of zero to be the "best" under most circumstances.

Comment: You are right. But I meant in general what do people mean by it and I need some more insight to understand why. Does that mean the antenna receives or radiates better when the SWR is better?

Comment: Two different things. The VSWR is a transmission line phenomenon; it has nothing to do with the effectiveness of any antenna it might be attached to -- just the ability to couple electrical energy to or from the antenna.

Comment: Good and bad are subjective measures. There was a radio amateur in the adjacent house and he created so strong fields into my home at HF bands that my audio recording studio got saturated and produced more his distorted SSB speech than music. I was not alone. Everyone in the neighbourhood suffered. But he had a perfectly valid license to spread his kilowatts. Time after time someone made his SWR better by rising it to infinity by cutting his antenna cable.

Comment: @user287001 How did you cut the cable? On the rooftop?

Comment: @user134429 I did dot cut it. It was someone else in the same house where he lived. The amateur lived in ground floor, the antenna cable was freely available between his window and the midpoint of his antenna which was between two high trees.

Comment: It may have been better to discuss it with the radio ham; they may not have known of the interference. The amateur licence says that the wireless apparatus must not cause interference. However, I don’t think you have a licence to destroy other people’s property. The ARRL (US) and RSGB (UK) have departments devoted to sorting out exactly this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the best VSWR you can get is unity, with a perfectly matched system.

This is equivalent to saying there is zero reflection, or a very large return loss. It tends to be the old timers and very high frequency applications that talk in terms of VSWR, as it could be measured with a slotted line and diode detector. Return loss tends to be the parameter favoured by most engineers.

In practice, you can get very, very close to a perfect match, with care, good load, good cable, clean connectors.

Comment: Thanks just to be sure: does that mean the antenna receives or radiates better when the SWR is better?

Comment: @user134429 A transmitter antenna will radiate whatever power it is fed equally well, regardless of the VSWR on the feeder to it. However, of the power produced by a power amplifier, more of that power will reach the antenna if the feeder between them has a good (nearer to unity) VWSR.

Comment: What is preferred by engineers is a whole bunch of measurements. 120dB return loss into a dummy load doesn't make a good antenna ;)